# Use faker.js to generate the form for casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs, faker

Casperjs can filling & submitting forms, but you need put it by your self and change it every time. Faker.js can generate the faker date which the form need. So, I just think how to combine it together? For example like this code::

```
var casper = require('casper');

var Faker = require('./Faker');

casper.start('http://contact.form', function() {

    this.fill('form#contact-form', {

     'name':   'Chuck Norris',

     'email':  'chuck@norris.com',

    }, true);

});

casper.start('http://contact.form', function() {

    this.fill('form#contact-form', {

     'name':   Faker.Name.findName(),

     'email':  Faker.Internet.email(),

    }, true);

});
```

Do you think is this correct or not?

Comment: Did you test it? It should work, your code seems good to me.

Comment: Yes, I test it use "casperjs XXX", but shows cannot find "./Faker"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script can't find "./Faker", try something like this:

```
sudo npm install -g Faker
```

And then:

```
var casper = require('casper');
var Faker = require('Faker');

// do your thing
```

Comment: Yes, I did it. And I can see the Faker folder in my workspace. But after I run it(casperjs test.js), they give me the information is:CasperError: Can't find module Faker